# How to change BackgroundColor property of a Frame from ViewModel or Codebehind - Xamarin Forms C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have this view with a ListView. I want to add a border whenever an Item is selected. My idea is to initially create a Frame with the same BackgroundColor as the contents. Then after an item is selected, I want to change the BackgroundColor to Red.

```
                <ListView
                    BackgroundColor="#e9e9e9"
                    HasUnevenRows="True"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ABC}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding XYZ}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    SeparatorColor="Transparent">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <ViewCell>

                                <StackLayout Padding="15" BackgroundColor="White">
                                    <Frame
                                        x:Name="BorderFrame"
                                        Padding="1"
                                        BackgroundColor="Aqua"
                                        CornerRadius="0">
                                        <Grid>

                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <extendedcontrols />
                                            <extendedcontrols />
                                            <extendedcontrols />
                                            <extendedcontrols />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Frame>

                                </StackLayout>

                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                </ListView>
```

Comment: Did you try `BorderFrame.BackgroundColor = ...;` in code behind? From viewmodel, its like any other `Binding`. `... BackgroundColor="{Binding FrameBackgroundColor}"...` Have you used MVVM Bindings?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I cant access with BorderFrame.BackgroundColor  because its inside a Template. And the last one you suggested, can you elaborate a bit like how am I gonna do it? I am new to MVVM and Xamarin. Thank you so much.

Comment: So what is the issue that you are facing I am not sure!!!

Comment: @FreakyAli I just want to know how do I do it, binding Frame's bgcolor to viewModel and change the bgcolor after an item is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were many existed cases about how to change the selected item's background in the listview.

At first, you can try to create a variable which is type of Color in the model and bind it to the `Frame's` backgroundcolor. And then add a ItemTapped event to the ListView. When the user taps the item in the listview, you can try to change the item's value to set the selected item's background color.

For more information, you can check the accepted answer in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63289909/change-background-color-of-listview-selected-item-in-xamarin).

In addition, you can also try add a tapped event to the viewcell in the listview's
and set the selected item's background color in the viewcell's tapped event in the code behind. And the accepted answer in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595003/how-can-i-change-background-color-of-items-of-a-listview-in-xaml) show the details.

Generally speaking, this issue had been mentioned for many times, so you can try to google about it before asking. Happy coding!

Comment: Zhang by 'When the user taps the item in the listview, you can try to change the item's value to set the selected item's background color.', did you mean sth like this?

private void listView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModel el = new ViewModel();
            el.SelectedBackgroundColor = Color.Red;
            
        }

Comment: No, just use the `ItemTapped` event, you can check the first link I provided. @tanzilshahriar